# How to access multiple json objects send in array django

Tags: javascript, django, jquery

I have this data passed in a POST to django view:

```
var jobj = [];

$('.some_class').each(function(){
                var ro = $('#some_id').html();  //html() output is number
                var nr = $('#something').html(); //html() output is number
                var item = {};
                  item["prog"] = ro;
                  item["act"] = nr;                    
                  jobj.push(item);
                 });
            arr = JSON.stringify(jobj);

     ajax_req = $.ajax({
     url: '../some_url/',
     type: "POST",
     data: {req_arr : arr},
     });
```

The data looks like this:

```
req_arr = [{"prog" : "1", "act" : "0"}, {"prog" : "2", "act" : "0"}, (...)]
```

Now in the view i want to loop over passed data, access it and then do something with it in sql:

```
def some_url(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    arr = request.POST['req_arr']
    for data in arr:
        prog = data['prog']
        act = data['act']
        (...) some sql stuff like SomeModel.objects.get(name=prog) (...)

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

I don't know how to access single values and keys, just like it would be python dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

While this is very old I found myself searching for this exact problem...

I found a way that works although I feel it is a bit unreliable

**Javascript:**

```
var rows = [];
$('.some_class').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var something = $(this).attr('data-something');
    var item = {};

    item["id"] = id;
    item["something"] = something;                    
    rows.push(JSON.stringify(item));
});

arr = rows.join("/");

ajax_req = $.ajax({
    url: '../some_url/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {req_arr : arr},
});
```

**views.py**

```
items = request.POST.get('req_arr', None)
items = str(items).split("/")

for i in range(0, len(items)):
    item = json.loads(items[i])
    id = item['id']
    something = item['something']
```